# Capacitor on iOS: POST request fails

Tags: ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using Ionic (v5) + React + Capacitor to create an app for iOS and I recently got stuck with a really strange error: fetch() and axios successfully perform GET requests to the backend while POST requests are always failing.

fetch() returns `"cancelled"` which tells me nothing but a failure meanwhile axios generates a more descriptive error:

```
{
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "capacitor://localhost/static/js/8.98344607.chunk.js:2:168604\ncapacitor://localhost/static/js/8.98344607.chunk.js:2:167548",
  "config": {
    "url": "auth",
    "method": "post",
    "data": "{\"email\":\"email-here\",\"password\":\"111111\"}",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "baseURL": "https://website.com/api/1.3/",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1
  }
}
```

Already checked Apache's CORS settings, it should be OK. Could anyone suggest a fix for this?

Upd.1: part of my code that performs all api requests

```
const axConf: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    url: query, // string
    method: m, // string
    baseURL: global.base_uri + 'api/' + global.api_version + '/',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: r, // object
    validateStatus: function (status) { return status >= 200 && status < 300; }
};
return new Promise(resolve => {
    axios(axConf)
        .then(response => resolve(successRes(r, i, response.data)))
        .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                if (error.response) {
                    resolve(errorRes(i, error.response));
                } else if (error.request) {
                    resolve(errorRes(i, error.request));
                } else {
                    resolve(errorRes(i, error.message));
                }
            }
        );
});
```

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after couple of days trying to solve this problem **I found the solution**.
Here it is, for everyone struggling with this:

This error happens when you try to perform a HTTP request and then something in your code breaks this request.
In my case that was the form: my fetch() request has been triggered by button's onClick action with `type="submit"` set on it and submitting the form itself triggered nothing but a state update which has been cancelling my request.

I was switching my app from Ionic v4 & Angular to Ionic v5 & React and previously the form didn't cause such behavior that's why I didn't even think this might be a thing.

I just removed onClick action from my button and set `onSubmit={handleLogin}` to the form itself. Then modified the code like this:

```
const handleLogin = (e: FormEvent) => {
    fnGetUserToken(loginData).then(...);
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Note the `e.preventDefault();` at the end.

In case you can not alter your code like this, I guess you could try to remove the property `type="submit"` from your button.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134764/3909488) that led me to this solution.

Comment: Same issue but this solution does not fit me.. :'(

Comment: @JeanR., I suppose you're using one of the latest Angular versions which perform the requests with RxJS library. Check your observables – I bet something in your code cancels them ahed of time.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was not having the url of my API in capacitor.config. So make sure

1. Your API is SSL-secured
2. On server side/API endpoint side/backend side send/add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response of your API (you have to add either `capacitor://localhost` or `ionic://localhost`)
3. Your capacitor.config (or capacitor.config.json in case you use quasar) looks like

```
{
  ...,
  "server": {
    "allowNavigation": [
      "path.to-your-api.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please more information on step 2

Comment: thanks thats work on step 2 :D i add capacitor://localhost on my project symfony on cros bundle and is work

Answer (score 1):

I spent days on this problem. The result: javascript calls have CORS issues in ionic and capacitor, so you need to run native calls especially in IOS to work.

A full blog essay can be found about this here:
https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-make-api-calls-in-ionic-capacitor-apps/179/#66d6

It finally solved the problem for me.

Comment: While CORS could cause a lot of pain during development, I mentioned that CORS was no longer an issue. Yet you did a great job and I'm glad that this SO page still helps people even after 1.5 years.

Comment: This post is a life saver. I had been using `CapacitorHttp` from `@capacitor/core`, but once I changed to `Http` from `@capacitor-community/http`, my post problem on iOS stopped. I know `CapacitorHttp` is the revamped and currently maintained version, but for some reason POST fails on iOS (okay on Android).